# Reverse line order in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to reverse the line order (considering `\r\n` line break) of a file using Notepad++?

Input:

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3

Required Output:

> Line 3
>   Line 2
>   Line 1

Any plugin/macro is OK

Comment: This is a good question.  I couldn't find anything, but I did find a related question for reversing a single line which required a Python script.  You may need to get a script for this.

Comment: Obviously the [newer version question](http://superuser.com/q/331098/391675) had more luck, anyway +1

Comment: The latest Notepad++ has a dedicated Menu Item for this: 

**Edit/Line Operations/Reverse Line Order**