# Regex: Change the order of the lines from the last one to first one (multiple files)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this lines (sentences) that must be changed in the opposite direction, from 40 to 1 (and vice versa) (into 125 files, that is why I need a regex solution) for multiple files.

```
1. I go home.
2. Imagine that...
3. I love you..
4. My name is..
5. Mother.. 
...
40. Finish
```

must become:

```
40. Finish 
...
5. Mother..
4. My name is..
3. I love you..
2. Imagine that...
1. I go home.
```

Comment: Notepad++ is not the right tool for such job with multiple files. You should write a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a plugin called Reverse Lines. To add it, on the menu bar click Plugins -> Plugins Admins. Find it on the list, select it then click Install. Notepad++ will close then reopen.

Open your document, click on Plugins -> Reverse Lines -> Document. The lines of your document will be reversed.

[image]
If all the lines start with numbers, then you don't need regex.
Click on Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines As Integers Descending. The lines will be re-ordered.

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks, working great. But I need a regex solution, because I have 125 files :)

Comment: @JustMe See edit. Another solution without the need of regex. You will need to add a plugin.

Comment: does it work for multiple files ?

Comment: @JustMe by multiple files you mean opened files?

Comment: not open, just being into a folder. I need to edit 250 files, I use search and replace in multiple files with notepad++

Answer (score 1):

As you are in windows, you can use powershell to do the reverse sort easily:

```
(Get-Content "Filepath") | Sort-Object -Descending | Set-Content "Filepath"
``°
If you wanna iterate over files then:
```

Get-childitem "Filepath" -Filter *.extension | foreach {
(Get-Content "$*.Fullname") | Sort-Object -Descending | Set-Content "$*.Fullname"
}

Comment: I add on .txt file with that text, and I write this in power shell `(Get-Content "d:\Downloads\Test\") | Sort-Object -Descending | Set-Content "d:\Downloads\Test\"`  DOESN'T WORK :)

Comment: @JustMe Use Foreachand get-childitem to iterate over items in file otherwise use the fullpath

Comment: don't understand, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I open powershell, I change the FILEPATH on yout formula, and nothing happen: `Get-childitem "d:\Downloads\Test\" -Filter *.extension | foreach { (Get-Content "$.Fullname") | Sort-Object -Descending | Set-Content "$.Fullname" }`