# Reverse text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-manipulation

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/165592/how-can-i-reverse-a-line-in-notepad) was asked several years ago without an accepted answer. The question has also long been inactive. Seems a simple piece of functionality, so perhaps a recent plugin provides the feature.

Say I have the text `Hello World!`. I'd like to select the text and have it replaced with `!dlroW olleH`. Ideally this would be a single option completely within Notepad++, either via a plugin or (simple) macro.

Ideally, complicated or non-general macros, regular expressions and external tools (such as online resources) should be avoided, if possible. But if you do know of some cool way to achieve this let me know!

Comment: this is just a suggestion but if you're that keen on notepad++ or any program then I think it's a bit mistaken to try to do everything completely native with no addons.. it's good to customize it. Just like with windows you customized it in a sense by not just using the native programs but adding notepad++

Comment: Fair comment...I'm not against customisation. Do you know of a plugin for Notepad++ that does this? I use a few plugins already, including the excellent `TextFX`. This provides some useful text manipulations (as well as some baffling ones!)...but not the simple ability to reverse text! :o) –

Comment: I am not a big user of notepad++ but I'm sure that a macro, whether an easy macro or a "complicated macro" could easily be added as an item in a menu or converted to a plugin and accessed in a menu just like the textfx menu or perhaps added to an existing menu. So you could ask how to make a menu item run a macro, or how to convert a macro to a plugin(then see how to have a plugin add to a menu like textfx does)

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully your comment is sufficient to imply such a solution could be offered, or do you think I need to edit the question?

Comment: Editing a question too drastically isn't always good move, like if it has some attempts at answering it  and those attempts become invalid with an edit to the question. And if a big change one could make it a new question. And who knows what answers may or may not come. Try to find a macro to do it, (often better to experiment/research yourself before asking), then you could set aside the question of reversing characters and look into how to run a macro from a menu, or from a button, or from a keyboard shortcut etc (often better to experiment/research yourself, then ask).

Comment: None of the answers, including the macro one, were ever accepted. Also, the macro appears to only work for a limited number of characters...so never tried it. Will give it a go, though. I think my question is reasonable. That question was asked over 7 years ago with no answer (apart from my own suggestion!) either new or simple. Surely there is something better in Notepad++ now?

Comment: I'd suggest a question of,  is it possible in notepad++ for a macro to reverse some characters.   I just looked up about macros in notepad++ and it seems they don't even use a language!! They sound rubbish.. You could look into other editors too, like brackets or sublime, those two are very popular with programmers. Sublime uses python.. TextFX does quite a few things so if TextFX can do that then maybe by the same kind of programming, a macro could do what you want. TextFX is maybe open source..

Comment: Have edited the question slightly. What do you think? If a reasonable edit, lets delete these comments...

Comment: If I were you i'd act more like a software engineer and ask myself how to write a simple macro or plugin to reverse text.  And i'd use textfx as a proof that it's possible to do something like it in notepad++ and i'd explore that avenue, and maybe ask a question about that and it'd be technical and programming related enough for stackoverflow..

Comment: Would love to develop a plugin offering such functionality for the community...but in the future...I'm also a software engineer with limited time! If someone's done it already, would just use that! :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python Script plugin that can be installed from Plugin Manager (pre Notepad++ v7.5) or from [the download site](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).

1. Select menu in `Plugins > Python Script > Show Console`
2. Select your text in the editor normally (*it gives unexpected result with a column/rectangular select mode*)
3. Enter the following code in the Python Console input (next to **>>>** symbol)

```py
editor.replaceSel(editor.getSelText().decode('utf-8')[::-1].encode('utf-8').replace("\n\r","\r\n"))
```

4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click **Run**

**Note:** If you selected multiple lines, the order of lines will be also reversed.

---

Additionally you can save that script by copying the code to a new blank tab, `Plugins > Python Script > New Script` then save it as "*reverse*".

Then you can access `Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > reverse` the next time you need to do the same operation.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Have found the working x64 version here:  https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/releases/tag/v1.0.9. Recommend manual installation (place `python27.dll` in %ProgramFiles%\Notepad++ and the `PythonScript` folder in %ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\plugins).

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/obfuscation-tools/reverse-text-generator/) isn't in Notepad++ itself, but I've used the site before and it seems to be able to do numerous other things with text.

For now, it might be the easiest option - just copy and paste your text from Notepad++ into the textbox, click Reverse Text, then copy and paste back to Notepad++.

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 Good answer, thanks. Not quite `The Answer` since it requires an external tool and an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with little Regular Expression, but using only NotePad ++  (tested on v.8.5.3):

- *(Select sentence to modify if not all the file)*
- Ctrl+h *(or Menu **SEARCH > Replace...**)*
- (Make sure the *Regular Expression* search mode is selected)
- Find: "(.)"
- Replace With: "\1\r\n"
- Press **Replace All**
- Menu **EDIT > Line Operations > Reverse Line Order**
- Ctrl+h
- Find: "(.)\r\n"
- Replace With: "\1"
- Press **Replace All**

All the text in the [selected] sentence should be reversed/mirrored after that.

Regards

Comment: Be aware that will not work if text have multiple lines. They will all be concatenated at the end of the process.

Comment: Interesting idea, though this does not work if inverting (only) one line among many, or just part of a single line. First copy the text to invert into a new document (Ctrl + N), then following the instructions. If you have multiple lines the line order is reversed, so this works best on a simple phrase.